# Using 10-2 vs. 12-2 for wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, receptacle, subpanel

I am considering using 10-2 to wire the opposite side of my house because of 12-2 voltage drop over 60ft distance. My house is 54x58 (see blueprint below). I called up Leviton and tech support says that their receptacles can handle from 14 to 10 gauge wire in the terminals.

REFERENCE:
http://home.leviton.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/RER15-Instruction-Sheet.pdf

If i do go this route:
   1. I'll have continuous runs of wiring without interruptions
   2. not much voltage drop as compared to 12-2
   3. Saves me time and money (2-2-2-1 SER runs for about $7/ft, i'll need around 70ft.

Any suggestions or is there something i am not considering?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use 10/2 wire for a lengthy 20A circuit?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109850/should-i-use-10-2-wire-for-a-lengthy-20a-circuit)

Comment: Slightly different. The other was about breaker compatibility,sizing with 10-2. This one is 10-2 vs 12-2 for receptacle and lighting  compatibility

Comment: You don't need to worry about voltage drop on a 60 foot run. Just run the 12/2. Appliances work just as well on 119 volts as they do on 122. Just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify your box fill #10 wire uses a 2.5 multiplier. You only have to count 1 ground wire, add up all the other wires in the box and multiply by 2.5 then add 5 for the device. If using boxes with clamps another 2.5 added to to the above will provide the minimum listed box size. The size in cubic inches required by code that is stamped on the box. Be aware that measuring the box and multiplying the length, width and depth gives a larger number than the listed size in table 314.16.A.